# Subquery commands out of sync

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, subquery, self-join

I'm running some SQL on PHPMyAdmin.

My table has the following fields:

```
address
firstname
joindate
memid
recommendedby
surname
telephone
zipcode
```

The `recommendedby` field contains member IDs. I would like to select members by name and list the people who recommended them by name. I've tried to do this with a subquery and a self-join:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(surname, ", ", firstname),
(SELECT CONCAT(m1.firstname, " ", m1.surname)
    FROM Members as m1
    INNER JOIN Members as m2
    ON m1.memid = m2.recommendedby) AS recommendedby
FROM Members
ORDER BY surname, firstname
```

This throws the error `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`. The subquery runs cleanly on its own. Does anyone know what is causing this error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example for your question:

```
CREATE TABLE #Members  (
  [address] VARCHAR(100),
firstname VARCHAR(100),
joindate VARCHAR(100),
memid int,
recommendedby int,
surname VARCHAR(100),
telephone VARCHAR(100),
zipcode VARCHAR(100),
);

INSERT INTO #Members
  ([address], firstname,surname,joindate,memid,recommendedby,telephone,zipcode)
VALUES
  ('adress1','Jack','Ady','2020-01-01',1,null,'0123455','104555'),
  ('adress2','Harry','Adwell','2020-01-02',2,3,'0123445455','1075'),
  ('adress3','John','Age','2020-01-03',3,4,'0124543455','1450855'),
  ('adress4','Robert','Ainslie','2020-01-04',4,1,'0124543455','10545055'),
  ('adress5','Yehuda','Aarons','2020-01-05',5,4,'0124543455','105595'),
  ('adress6','Michael','Altis','2020-01-01',6,1,'0124543455','1012')
  ;
  

  select CONCAT(m1.firstname, '-', m1.surname) MemberName,
  CONCAT(m2.firstname, '-', m2.surname)recommendedMember
  from #Members m1 
  left join #Members m2 on m1.memid = m2.recommendedby
```

result =

```
MemberName         recommendedMember
Jack-Ady           Robert-Ainslie
Jack-Ady           Michael-Altis
Harry-Adwell       -
John-Age           Harry-Adwell
Robert-Ainslie     John-Age
Robert-Ainslie     Yehuda-Aarons
Yehuda-Aarons      -
Michael-Altis      -
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be fine without the `join`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.surname, ', ', m.firstname),
      (SELECT CONCAT(m1.firstname, ' ', m1.surname)
       FROM Members m1
       WHERE m1.memid = m.recommendedby
      ) AS recommendedby
FROM Members m;
```

You can also do this with a `LEFT JOIN` in the outer query.  But not `JOIN` is necessary in the subquery -- only a correlation clause.

Comment: This doesn't work--it just fills the `recommendedby` field with the same `CONCAT(m1.firstname, ' "' m1.surname)`, regardless of the `recommendedby` member ID.

Comment: @Yehuda . . .  I don't understand your comment at all.  This uses a correlated subquery to get the name of the recommended by member.  If you set up a SQL/DB fiddle, this will be easy to demonstrate.

Comment: See the following screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkz3C.png

Comment: @Yehuda . . . Your screen shot has three columns, but this query only returns two.

Comment: I added the `recommendedby` column next to the column you advised so that you can see how it is not working properly.

Comment: @Yehuda . . . Set up a SQL/DB fiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I've created the fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2JrHaa3FyRRY6bYEWfzK4X/2

Comment: @Yehuda . . . It works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82ae2dac3459d00b899e63770184ea4c.